# import data from aws s3 to mysql or any non aws database

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, hive

I am new to aws. I have data in my s3 bucket in csv format.how can i load that data into mysql or hive. if not can you show me a way to import data from s3 to any other non aws database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would load the data in exactly the same way you would normally load data into the desired target.

If the target does not know how to import directly from Amazon S3, then download the data and load it in the normal way.